# Flex httpservice faults

Tags: apache-flex, air, httpservice

I've been given a Flex application which made use of a RESTFUL service.

I've managed to create a SQLite DB which stored data from the service and now I would like the application to be able to run offline and make use of the data existing in it's local DB. This works fine the only problem is that the httpService object throws a fault when it cannot connect.

If I don't provide a method to handle the fault event then it is displayed in an error window.
If I provide a blank method to handle the fault then it is still displayed in an error window.

How can I get it to stop displaying this error Window?

Regards,
Craig

Comment: What is the message in the window that you are getting?

Comment: By chance, are you bubbling up events to another handler that could be showing the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never Mind... Problem was that something else was generating the same fault...

Answer (score 0):

Check for a network connection before making the httpservice request.

[Flex 3 - Adobe Flex 3 Help - Network Connectivity](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/html/help.html?content=network_connectivity_1.html)

That way, when an exception occurs it's really an unexpected behavior instead of something that could be regular program usage.

Comment: As good an idea as that is... I was looking for some help to understand the error handling in Flex...